# Establishing why one profile is faster than all others

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, performance, user-profile

We have a webapp that we launch out through Citrix for external users. This webapp displays documents through an ActiveX control (the Oracle OutsideIn File Viewer). For most users, flicking between documents takes ~1.6 seconds, but for one user it only takes 0.6 seconds. We would like all users to have this performance.

However, we've been totally unsuccessful in establishing what it is about this profile that makes it so much faster.

We don't have roaming profiles set up. We do know it's that specific user profile on that specific box.

We tried cloning the system and using sysprep to make the fast profile the default user, however whatever sysprep does didn't carry over the magic that makes it fast.

We're totally at a loss as to where to even start establishing what makes this different. We've gone through all the IE settings we possibly could. We've tried looking through ProcMon logs without anything jumping out. Our suspicion is it's to do with the way files are downloaded by the ActiveX control and saved to a temp location, but we're really not sure how to go about changing behaviour.

So, in short, any ideas on how to clone profiles not using sysprep (supported or unsupported) or how to run down the differences between two very similar user profiles would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several factors...

If it's file access related, you can try using Sysinternals tools to see what file/registry calls are being made and get some sense of timing for what's being called and how long it takes to respond. You might try the procmon tool on the server and client and compare what's happening.

If it's a network issue, you can compare the settings on the switch (managed?) to see if there are differences in the port. You can also test the line to see what kind of noise there is and whether there's something slowing access on the wire.

Also check with a sniffer to see what the network traffic is doing.

You've narrowed down to variables to see if it's that specific user and just that box? I.e., if speedy user goes to a coworker's machine, does he log in slow like the coworker? And the coworker on the speedy user's system is still slow?

Are there any differences in the user objects in AD that could cause some form of permission issue?